# TableView Separator appears at the cell wrong height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I set heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate return value to 100.0f
It appears that the height is works except for the first cell

[image]

But even worse, when I touch the cell, it has the right height 100.0f

[image]

The code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // For user profile cell
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        FSMeHeaderCell *cell = (FSMeHeaderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kHeaderCellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[FSMeHeaderCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kHeaderCellIdentifier];
        }
    }
    else {
       // ...... another cell
    }

    // ......
    return cell;
}
```

I also tested it with a default cell that comes with UIKit, but resulting the same effect.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"defaultTestId";
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"defaultTestId"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";

    return cell;
}
```

It's default cell, and still has this issue.

### UPDATE

I try to set the cell.frame's height, weirdly, it seems it **solve** this problem.
But, when I log it with

```
CGRect frame = cell.frame;
frame.size.height = 100.0f;
cell.frame = frame;

NSLog(@"cell frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
```

It still has height of 44.0f (default), unchanged.

I have seen a lot of this question in stackoverflow without answer 
What makes the separator line appears at the wrong height?

Comment: you should post your code so that somebody can analyse it.

Comment: i think that it's something wrong with cellForRow method, please give us more informative code

Comment: Post your code for `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods. Also have you set the default cell height either in IB or in code?

Comment: If you target iOS8 you can use autolayout to automatically adjust cell height and avoid that trouble.

Comment: @RoboticCat I don't use interface builder, only full code.
I'll update the question with the code.

Comment: If you aren't using IB and setting row heights at design time, then somewhere you need to set the rowHeight (i.e. `tableView.rowHeight = 100.0f` or `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`) or use self-sizing cells (i.e.  `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0f` and `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` or `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`). Setting the cell's framed does not sound like a great idea & seems fragile. Better would be to design the custom cell so that the constraints defined the size.

Comment: @RoboticCat Yes, I set the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath, the problem is the separator line appears in the middle of the cell.
When I also set the cell's frame height, it solve the problem.
But without any explanations.